# Using eth0 and ppp interfaces in an interchangeable mode

Tags: networking, debian, linux, ethernet

I've a Debian system without a UI, with a GPRS modem attached to it. Now, this system is connected with Ethernet through a standard cable.

I want to obtain a configuration that allows the computer to access the Internet via Ethernet if an Ethernet cable is connected, otherwise use the GPRS to do so. Practically speaking, I want the *eth0* interface to be the preferable interface if it is on, and *ppp* (only) if the former isn't mounted.

How do I obtain an easy *[/etc/network/interfaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/interfaces.5.html)* configuration to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are `if-up.d` and `if-down.d` directories in `/etc/ppp/`. You should put `ifup` and `ifdown` scripts there to configure your default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Debian system has `/sbin/ip help` and `/etc/iprout??/`, iproute2 gives you the both a system-wide default gateway and a NIC/interface specific default gateway.

It is called source-based routing, as opposed to destination-based routing. The source in your case is the GPRS modem. See policyrouting.org or download [Alexey Kuznetsov's IP command reference](https://homepage.smc.edu/morgan_david/cs70/ip-cref.pdf).

Comment: Can you add a primary reference to Alexey Kuznetsov's piece (1999?)?